# QGIS Error between EPSG and custom SRC

Tags: qgis, gdal, proj

This is an error I get since the day I changed to 2.x to 3.x version.
Today, I am trying to fix it. I had QGIS 3.10 on Linux Mint from the repositories.

Then, I have uninstalled all, and I have installed from the [site](https://qgis.org/es/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu)

Following instruction, and [fixing a issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309161/dpkg-error-processing-package-qgis-providers-configure) than unabled to me to configure any things, I got 3.28 version.

But the error I wanted to fix is still there.
[image]

Translated (more or less):

> No transformation available between EPSG:25830 - ETRS89 / UTM zone 30N
> and custom SRC: GEOGCRS["unknown",DATUM["unknown",ELLIPSOID["GRS
> 1…. proj_create_operations: SQLite error on SELECT name, type,
> coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name,
> datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition,
> deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such
> column: area_of_use_auth_name

If I start QGIS from console, I get those info (and errors):

```
using qt5ct plugin
D-Bus global menu: no
proj_create_from_database: SQLite error on SELECT name, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, geodetic_crs_auth_name, geodetic_crs_code, conversion_auth_name, conversion_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM projected_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name
proj_create_from_database: SQLite error on SELECT name, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, geodetic_crs_auth_name, geodetic_crs_code, conversion_auth_name, conversion_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM projected_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name
proj_create_from_database: SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name
proj_create_from_database: SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name
```

And when I try to open a project like the picture, I get those errors:

> GDAL ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: SQLite error on SELECT name,
> ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code, prime_meridian_auth_name,
> prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code,
> publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum WHERE auth_name = ?
> AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name GDAL ERROR 1:
> PROJ: proj_as_wkt: SQLite error on SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name,
> ellipsoid_code, prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code,
> area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated
> FROM geodetic_datum WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name GDAL ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: SQLite error on
> SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code,
> prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name,
> area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum
> WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name GDAL ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database:
> SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name,
> coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code,
> area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated
> FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name Warning 4: Failed to open
> /usr/share/qgis/resources/data/world_map.gpkg: Permiso denegado. ERROR
> 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: SQLite error on SELECT name, type,
> coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name,
> datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition,
> deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such
> column: area_of_use_auth_name Warning 4: Failed to open
> /usr/share/qgis/resources/data/world_map.gpkg: Permiso denegado. ERROR
> 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: SQLite error on SELECT name, type,
> coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name,
> datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition,
> deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such
> column: area_of_use_auth_name ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_identify: SQLite
> error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name,
> coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code,
> area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated
> FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name GDAL ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: SQLite error on
> SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code,
> prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name,
> area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum
> WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name GDAL ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: SQLite error on
> SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code,
> prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name,
> area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum
> WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name GDAL ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: SQLite error on
> SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code,
> prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name,
> area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum
> WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name GDAL ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database:
> SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name,
> coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code,
> area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated
> FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_identify: SQLite error on
> SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name,
> coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code,
> area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated
> FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name GDAL ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: SQLite error on
> SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code,
> prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name,
> area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum
> WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name GDAL ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: SQLite error on
> SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code,
> prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name,
> area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum
> WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name GDAL ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: SQLite error on
> SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code,
> prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name,
> area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum
> WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_identify: SQLite error on
> SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name,
> coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code,
> area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated
> FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name GDAL ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database:
> SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name,
> coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code,
> area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated
> FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> area_of_use_auth_name

**UPDATE**

This is shown when I type `proj -v`

```
Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020
<proj>: 
projection initialization failure
cause: no arguments in initialization list
program abnormally terminated
```

Comment: Could you provide the full definition of "SRC personalizado"? Looking at the provided text, seems that the datum is not properly defined. I assume that you are in Spain. I can only imagine that you use ETRS89 or ED50 for very old data. But "unnamed" does not sound very good..

Comment: @Javier I forgot to translate it. I think that it can be translated like "custom SRC". I have updated. And yes, from Spain. But I don't understand...I know that ED50 is for old data, but I hadn' t noticed that ETRS89 too. I think that it is the SRC used by Catastro in Spain

Comment: What I am asking is for the full wkt, not for the translation. Spanish is not the problem.
Let me rephrase the sentence: "I can only imagine that you use ETRS89 (or ED50 for very old data)". So, why do you have in Spain a Custom datum? It is very strange. If it were ETRS89, it should be there as ETRS89, not as "custom" or "unnamed".
Maybe if you provide the file we can try to understand more. Where is the file coming from?

Comment: @Javier. All the layers are setting on EPSG:25830 - -ETRS89/ UTM zone 30N as well as the current project. When I start a new session this info dissappear and puts "custom SRC". I have read about similar problems, but I don't know hox can I solved. Think is related wit libproj. I'll updated my message showing the output of `proj -v` . Thx!

Comment: Could you provide the file that is producing the error?

Comment: @Javier. Sorry for the delay. I think that the problem was that I had `libproj15 v6.3.1`and `proj-data 8.2` (I think...8.x anyway). I have fixed looking for properly proj-data. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finnaly looks as I had a similar problems seen here.
I have `libproj15 6.3.1-1` package and I had a 8.x `proj-data` version.
I have downloaded and installed the properly version from here:
https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/proj-data_6.3.1-1_all.deb.html and now it works fine. It's something related with the new `proj.db` in 8.1 can't be readed with `libproj 6.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question and your answer. I got this error (*no such column: area_of_use_auth_name*) on Windows when I used an older version of ogr2ogr.exe. In my case I was using the ogr from the geotools/Mapserver GDAL. When I switched to the Postgres/13/bin/ogr2ogr.exe then the error didn't come up any more.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with anaconda3 (thanks to @user3733164's answer)

```
# Download proj-data
cd ~/Downloads/
mkdir proj-data
cd proj-data/
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/proj/proj-data_6.3.1-1_all.deb

# Extract deb
ar x proj-data_6.3.1-1_all.deb
tar -xvf data.tar.xz

# Backup and replace proj.db
cd ~/anaconda3/
mv ./share/proj/proj.db ./share/proj/proj.db.old
cp ~/Downloads/proj-data/usr/share/proj/proj.db ./share/proj/proj.db
```