GDAL bin error regarding PROJ issue
GDAL bin error regarding PROJ issue!!
I have been trying to setup an elevation API in Ubuntu 20.04 server. For this elevation API, the first process is downloading a TIFF file, and then we convert the .tif file to an .sql file. While doing this I am getting the below error in script.

My GDAL version installed in server is 3.3.2 and gdal version used in PostgreSQL is GDAL 3.0.4.
How can I sort out this issue?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question so the error message is in the body as text. Images are not legible on all devices and can't be searched by others to find your Question.

The proj.db database file in your system comes from some other version of Proj than what GDAL is using. See for example https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/444102/qgis-error-between-epsg-and-custom-src.

@user30184 While i am installing postgis automatically libproj15:amd64 and libproj19:amd64 are getting installed. Is it because 2 libproj are running simultaneously?

Will you please add details about how you installed postresql and postgis.

For postgresql i ran the command apt-get -y install postgresql and for postgis i ran the command apt install postgis postgresql-13-postgis-3.

@jbalk If possible could you tell me what the issue might be?

@jbalk For more info, I am using a particular command (raster2pgsql) to convert tif files to sql files. While running the command, I am getting the above error for file conversion.

What @user30184 said in their comment.  I'm sorry but I don't know how to fix it.  You can probably specify which proj to use in the gdal command
