Merge multiple JP2 images into a single GeoTIFF with GDAL
On QGIS they appear like this, overlaid on the OSM map. Here you can download the JP2 image set.

I'm trying to merge them with GDAL with this script
CD C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python37\Scripts
set "input_dir=C:\GDAL-Workspace\tiles\test"
set "output_dir=C:\GDAL-Workspace\merge\test"
set "merged_image=%output_dir%\merged.tif"

set "file_list="
for %%I in ("%input_dir%\*.jp2") do (
    set "file_list=!file_list! %%I"
)
python3 -m gdal_merge -o "%merged_image%" %file_list%

But I get this error message:
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: SQLite error on SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code, prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name


You have mixed Proj versions on your computer. The proj.db file that is in your proj_data directory does not match with the Proj program version. See for example https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/444102/qgis-error-between-epsg-and-custom-src.

@user30184 I downloaded GDAL from OSGeo4W. How can I check the version of proj.db?

You have probably the proj.db file in C:\OSGeo4W\share\proj. The vesion info is in the table named "metadata". You can read it with any SQLite software, or with ogrinfo ogrinfo proj.db -sql "select * from metadata".
